# Issue while deploying app on tomcat 6.0.28

Tags: grails, deployment, tomcat6

I am facing a problem that I am not able to deploy my grails application on the tomcat, I am following the below written steps:

1. `grails prod war`
2. `mv target/app.war /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps`
3. Restart the tomcat using `sudo service stop`

The problem is that my server starts up but it does not deploy the war, since when I goto `/myapp`, I get a 404.

The logs that I get are :

`

```
Configuring Spring Security ...
System properties loaded from: /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/jbilling/WEB-INF/classes/jbilling.properties
Resolved jbilling resources directory to: 
Apr 11, 2012 4:25:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Apr 11, 2012 4:25:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/jbilling] startup failed due to previous errors
Apr 11, 2012 4:25:30 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/jbilling] registered the JBDC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Apr 11, 2012 4:25:30 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/jbilling] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null] (value [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory$2@127ea69]) and a value of type [java.lang.Boolean] (value [false]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
Apr 11, 2012 4:26:33 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/jbilling/WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec-1.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Apr 11, 2012 4:26:33 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/jbilling/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.3.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Loading configuration files from classpath
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: stacktrace.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:207)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:290)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.logging.Log4jConfig.createFullstackTraceAppender(Log4jConfig.groovy:177)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.logging.Log4jConfig.this$2$createFullstackTraceAppender(Log4jConfig.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.logging.Log4jConfig$this$2$createFullstackTraceAppender.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:147)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.logging.Log4jConfig.configure(Log4jConfig.groovy:145)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.logging.Log4jConfig$configure.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.logging.Log4jConfig.configure(Log4jConfig.groovy:92)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.contextInitialized(Log4jConfigListener.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1276)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:625)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Log4j XML Plugin - please put a log4j.groovy or log4j.xml under /grails-app/conf, or uninstall this plugin
```

`

I even have a log4j.xml file under the folder path /usr/share/tomcat6/bin/grails-app/conf.

I tried googling but I could not comprehend the solutions which were give, Can someone please help ?

Comment: Your application does not have permission to write to that file location.

Comment: @RomainHippeau: How can I resolve that , and BTW, when I check for the stacktrace.log file, I dont find it.

Comment: log4j is trying to write to a folder which it doesn't have permissions to write to. Point log4j to explicitly write to a directory and give that directory write permissions.

Comment: @RiteshMNayak: How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I just saw this error in our log files here at work.  It didn't prevent our app from loading though.

We are cleaning up our logs so here is the fix: in the `Config.groovy` file in the log4j enclosure put

```
appenders {
    'null' name:'stacktrace'
}
```